# how to switch with different tags ( dropdown and list ) depending on the selection of third dropdown's item?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have 2 dropdownlist(lets say A and B) and 1 listItem (lets say C).  I need to switch between dropdown (B) and listitem (C) depending on option selected on first dropdown (A) which has only two options. How do you switch like this using javascript?

```
  <tr id="trInclude" runat="server">
        <td class="label" valign="top">Include : </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExpiring" runat="server" Visible="true"  onchange="reloadDisplayBfys(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Only Expiring"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Label ID="lblFunds" runat="server" Text="Funds" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" valign="top" width="300">
            <asp:Label ID="lblBFY" runat="server" Text="Expiring budget fiscal year:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td valign="top">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstBudgetFiscalYear" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="5" Visible="false">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="" class="all" />
            </asp:ListBox>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBudgetFiscalYear" runat="server" Visible="false" onchange="reloadFY(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="" class="all"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>


 function reloadDisplayBfys(index) {
        var bel = document.getElementById("<%= ddlExpiring.ClientID%>");
        var bfy;
        if (bel.selectedIndex) {
            bfy = bel.options[bel.selectedIndex].value;
        }
        if (bfy == 0) {
            document.getElementById("<%= lstBudgetFiscalYear.ClientID%>").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("<%= ddlBudgetFiscalYear.ClientID%>").style.display = "none"; 
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("<%= lstBudgetFiscalYear.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("<%= ddlBudgetFiscalYear.ClientID%>").style.display = "block";

        }
    }
```

Comment: I started to answer but realized I don't fully understand your question. Can you clarifiy what it means "to switch between dropdown (B) and listitem (C)"? And which elements in your sample code represent each of the three entities dropdown (A), dropdown (B), and listitem (C)?

Comment: Hi @Cat , In above code "ddlexpiring" means dropdown (A), "ddlBudgetFiscalYear" means  dropdown (B) and "lstBudgetFiscalYear"means  listitem (C). Here If value = 1 selected on "ddlexpiring"  then display dropdown  "ddlBudgetFiscalYear" and it should be default else if value = 0 then display  listItem "lstBudgetFiscalYear". Thanks

Comment: I'm going to be busy for a few hours, but I'll check back in on this when I'm free again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I updated my answer to meet these specifications (assuming you wanted to display the custom option inside the second dropdown.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If asp:DropDownList works just like an html `select` element, then your selector for the value looks right. One way to use it would be to skip the "onchange" attribute and use a regular event listener like in the code below.

---

(Edited to meet the specifications in your response)
This solution uses a template element to store your `lstFiscalYear` option, which is conditionally inserted/removed:

```js
const firstDropdown = document.getElementById("firstDropdown"),
      secondDropdown = document.getElementById("secondDropdown");
firstDropdown.addEventListener("change", updateDisplay);

function updateDisplay(event){
  const isInitialState = secondDropdown.options[0].value == "default",
        useInitialState = parseInt(firstDropdown.value) == 0;
  if(isInitialState && !useInitialState){
    alternativeOption = document.getElementById("alternativeOptionTemplate").content.cloneNode(true);
    secondDropdown.insertBefore(alternativeOption, secondDropdown.options[0]); 
    secondDropdown.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
  else if(!isInitialState && useInitialState){
    secondDropdown.removeChild(secondDropdown.options[0]);
    secondDropdown.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
else{ /* User selected neither 0 nor 1 */ }
}
```

```html
<select id="firstDropdown">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
</select>

<template id="alternativeOptionTemplate">
  <option value="lastFiscalYear">Info about last fiscal year</option>
</template>  

<select id="secondDropdown">
  <option value="default">Default</option>
</select>
```